OpenAI Assistants API: How do I use it instead of the Completions or Chat Completions API?
I have an assistant with an ID created at https://platform.openai.com/.
I want to use it instead of the Completions API or Chat Completions API. How do I do that?
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();
import { OpenAI } from "openai";
import readline from "readline";

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.API_KEY });

const userInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

let messages = [];

userInterface.prompt();
userInterface.on("line", async (input) => {
  messages.push({ role: "user", content: input });

  const res = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: contextMessages,
  });
  const assistantMessage = res.choices[0].message.content;
  console.log(assistantMessage);
  messages.push({ role: "assistant", content: assistantMessage });
  userInterface.prompt();
});

I can fetch the assistant through the API by creating a thread and a run like below. I just don't know how to use it in the code above, so the user is chatting with my assistant.
const emptyThread = await openai.beta.threads.create();

const run = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(emptyThread.id, {
  assistant_id: "asst_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
});

console.log(run);


Using the OpenAI Assistants API is fundamentally different (i.e., more complex) than using any other APIs, like the Completions API or Chat Completions API.
I've made a YouTube tutorial on how to use the Assistants API and posted the code on my GitHub profile.
Here are the steps you need to follow to get a response from the assistant:
Step 1: Create an assistant
The easiest way to do this is to use the OpenAI platform.


Step 2: Create a thread
Python:
my_thread = client.beta.threads.create()

Node.js:
const myThread = await openai.beta.threads.create();


Step 3: Add a user's message to the thread
Python:
my_thread_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
    thread_id=my_thread.id,
    role="user",
    content=user_input,
)

Node.js:
const myThreadMessage = await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(
  (thread_id = myThread.id),
  {
    role: "user",
    content: userInput,
  }
);


Step 4: Run the assistant
Python:
my_run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
    thread_id=my_thread.id,
    assistant_id=assistant_id,
)

Node.js:
const myRun = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(
  (thread_id = myThread.id),
  {
    assistant_id: assistantID,
  }
);


Step 5: Periodically retrieve the run to check its status to see if it has moved to completed
Note: This is the trickiest part. See the code for the Step 5 and Step 6 below.

Step 6: Retrieve the assistant's response
Python:
# Periodically retrieve the run to check its status
while my_run.status in ["queued", "in_progress"]:
    keep_retrieving_run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
        thread_id=my_thread.id, run_id=my_run.id
    )

    # If the run status is completed
    if keep_retrieving_run.status == "completed":
        # Retrieve the assistant's response
        all_messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=my_thread.id)

        # Display the assistant's response
        print(f"Assistant: {all_messages.data[0].content[0].text.value}")

        break
    elif keep_retrieving_run.status in ["queued", "in_progress"]:
        pass
    else:
        break

Node.js:
// Asynchronous function to retrieve the run status and display the assistant's response
async function retrieveRun(threadId, runId) {
  while (true) {
    const keepRetrievingRun = await openai.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
      (thread_id = threadId),
      (run_id = runId)
    );

    if (keepRetrievingRun.status === "completed") {
      // Retrieve the messages added by the assistant to the thread
      const allMessages = await openai.beta.threads.messages.list(
        (thread_id = threadId)
      );

      // Display assistant message
      console.log("Assistant: ", allMessages.data[0].content[0].text.value, "\n");

      break;
    } else if (
      keepRetrievingRun.status === "queued" ||
      keepRetrievingRun.status === "in_progress"
    ) {
      // Pass
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

await retrieveRun(myThread.id, myRun.id);

See the full Python code or the full Node.js code.
